# virtual keyboard in JS but with images

Tags: javascript, html, css, keyboard, virtual

I want to make a virtual keyboard in HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. However, there is a twist. Instead of the letters on the keyboard, I would like to replace them with images of my own choice. So lets say,

```
instead of letter "a", i have an image of APPLE
instead of letter "s", I have an image of SNAKE
```

Was able to do it.

Comment: if everything on the keyboard is going to be represented by an image, replace the elements in keyLayout with src's to your images.  Then create your html and insert the src for each key

Comment: Could you show more of your code? It isn't clear how the bit you have shown is actually used/does anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is this what you had in mind?

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("key");

var myFunction = function(event) {
let text = document.getElementById('text')
text.innerText = text.innerText + event.target.id
   
};

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
}
```

```css
.keyboard{
display:flex;
justify-content:center;
}

img{
border:solid 2px green;
}
```

```html
<div class='keyboard'>
<img src="https://unsplash.it/50/50.jpg?image=1" id='a' class='key'> 
<img src="https://unsplash.it/50/50.jpg?image=2" id='b' class='key'> 
<img src="https://unsplash.it/50/50.jpg?image=3" id='c' class='key'> 
<img src="https://unsplash.it/50/50.jpg?image=4" id='d' class='key'> 
<img src="https://unsplash.it/50/50.jpg?image=5" id='e' class='key'> 
<img src="https://unsplash.it/50/50.jpg?image=6" id='f' class='key'> 
<img src="https://unsplash.it/50/50.jpg?image=7" id='g' class='key'> 
</div>
<div class='keyboard'>
<img src="https://unsplash.it/50/50.jpg?image=81" id='h' class='key'> 
<img src="https://unsplash.it/50/50.jpg?image=82" id='i' class='key'> 
<img src="https://unsplash.it/50/50.jpg?image=83" id='j' class='key'> 
<img src="https://unsplash.it/50/50.jpg?image=84" id='k' class='key'> 
<img src="https://unsplash.it/50/50.jpg?image=85" id='l' class='key'> 
<img src="https://unsplash.it/50/50.jpg?image=88" id='m' class='key'> 
<img src="https://unsplash.it/50/50.jpg?image=87" id='n' class='key'> 
</div>

<div id='text'>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use HTML AND CSS Grid to do that, you just need the images and a file you can take them out of, unless there is an interactiveness to your website you won't be needing javascript